# Run a controller function whenever a view is opened/shown

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an app with angular+ionic that uses a classic three-button menu at the bottom with three ion-tabs in it. When a user clicks a tab, that template opens through ui-router.

I have states like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('other', {
    url: "/other",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/other/other.html"
})
```

In the template I do something like:

```
<ion-nav-view name="other" ng-init="doSomething()"></ion-nav-view>
```

I'm aware that I can write the doSomething() function in my controller and just call it manually there. That gives me the same problem though. I can't seem to figure out how to call the doSomething() function more than once, whenever somebody opens that view.

Right now, the doSomething() function gets called just fine, but only the first time that view/tab gets opened by the user. I'd like to call a function (to update geolocation) whenever a user opens that view or tab.

What would be a correct way to implement that?

Comment: try {{doSomething()}}  ?

Comment: the problem isn't with doSomething() as that's launching just fine, it's just that it won't trigger twice. The first time the view opens it runs fine, the second time it seems like it's just loading up a cached view or something?

Comment: ng-init calls the function only once. you can call ng-controller="doSomething()" or {{doSomething()}} in your partial views and function gets fired whenever router/partial called.

Comment: in your config state, set your cache to false. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you have assigned a certain controller to your view, then your controller will be invoked every time your view loads. In that case, you can execute some code in your controller as soon as it is invoked, for example this way:

```
<ion-nav-view ng-controller="indexController" name="other" ng-init="doSomething()"></ion-nav-view>
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('indexController', function($scope) {
    /*
        Write some code directly over here without any function,
        and it will be executed every time your view loads.
        Something like this:
    */
    $scope.xyz = 1;
});
```

**Edit:** You might try to track state changes and then execute some code when the route is changed and a certain route is visited, for example:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

You can find more details here: [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I'm doing. This code will only run once, the first time the view was openend. I've tried to log something to my console and it only triggers the first time.

Comment: When you say it works in your app, are you talking about an ionic app as well? I'm trying to see if that might be the case it's not working for me.

Comment: Working with stateChange does the trick, just clicking on a tab still only runs once. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: I think this has to do with the way Ionic caches certain parts of your app. maybe setting ```cache-view``` to false will help? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/ search for cache-view

Comment: This is perhaps the issue with the recent release of ionic. However, you can also disable cache on the routes level. just add a cache : false to each and every route in your routes configuration.

Comment: What is `doSomething()`? It doesn't appear in the controller code.

Comment: @ManishKr.Shukla what about if i want to test that code which you suggested to add in beginning of the controller ?

Answer (score 87):

By default, your controllers were cache and that is why your controller only fired once. To turn off caching for a certain controller you have to modify your `.config(..).state` and set the `cache` option to `false`. eg :

```
  .state('myApp', {
    cache: false,
    url: "/form",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/form.html",
        controller: 'formCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

for further reading please visit http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: Very useful for a logout controller

Comment: It's really unfortunate that caching is turned on by default in ionic. Seems like this should be an opt-in feature instead of adding it by default.

Comment: I only needed to reload one state so I used: `$state.go('app.statename', {}, {reload:true});`([more info](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#state-1), [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30224972/4815184)).

Comment: While this works it's not exactly the right way to go about it. It's going to slow your app down - assuming you don't want to go through the entire controller init procedure every time the user switches to that view, I think jczaplew's answer is a nicer approach.

Comment: Great stuff. I had disabled caching across the entire app. Glad I came across this answer

Comment: I am trying to disable the `cache : false` in chat app it will not loading the chat history. any change required in code so that it will work and controller is initialize in userList and chatting controller from the beginning every time.

Answer (score 50):

Following up on the answer and link from [AlexMart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3367584/alexmart), something like this works:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
     // Code you want executed every time view is opened
     console.log('Opened!')
  })
})
```

Comment: **`$ionicView.beforeEnter` is probably what you want.**  `$ionicView.enter` fires [after "the view has fully entered"](http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-the-changes/).  If you are using animated view transitions, using `$ionicView.beforeEnter` executes *before* your transition starts.  This means that you can be running your code *during* the transition which will likely lead to a "snappier" feel in your app.

Comment: I think this is just the simplest and clean answer. Regarding @rinogo comment, I think that each programmer may decide on whether to use "enter" or "beforeEnter", according to whatever happens in the view/controller. The important thing to understand here is that you can handle life cycle events to call a function every time you enter your view.

Answer (score 12):

I faced at the same problem, and here i leave the reason of this behavior for everyone else with the same issue.

> View LifeCycle
>
> In order to improve performance, we've improved Ionic's ability to cache view elements and scope data. Once a controller is initialized, it may persist throughout the app’s life; it’s just hidden and removed from the watch cycle. Since we aren’t rebuilding scope, we’ve added events for which we should listen when entering the watch cycle again.

To see full description and $ionicView events go to:
http://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-changes/

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you disable the view cache with **cache-view="false"**?

In your view add this to the ion-nav-view like that:

```
<ion-nav-view name="other" cache-view="false"></ion-nav-view>
```

Or in your stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider.state('other', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/other',
   templateUrl : 'templates/other/other.html'
})
```

Either one will make your controller being called always.

Comment: Wont this have performance side-effects? I supposed the view is cached so that the whole view isn't reloaded each time. Disabling this feature wouldn't cause the whole page to load again, whereas we only want a piece of code to be executed again?

Comment: Probably, yes @Sindarus. But there is a few case that is necessary. To me, I have a plugin drawing on the view and I couldn't figure it out how to clean it.

Comment: This was a perfect solution for my case, I was logging out the user then visiting the controller again, I don't want to cache, and everything should be re-initialized. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For example to @Michael Trouw,

inside your controller put this code.
this will run everytime when this state is entered or active, you do not need to worry about disabling cache and it's a better approach.

```
.controller('exampleCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
        // Any thing you can think of
        alert("This function just ran away");   
    });
})
```

You can have more examples of flexibility like $ionicView.beforeEnter -> which runs before a view is shown. And there are some more to it.

Answer (score 2):

Considering Ionic's ability to cache view elements and scope data mentioned above, this might be another way of doing, if you want to run the controller every time the view gets loaded. You can globally disable the caching mechanism used by ionic by doing:

`$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`

Else, the way I had it working for me was doing

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.afterLeave", function () {
     $ionicHistory.clearCache();
});
```

This is to clear the cache before leaving the view to re-run controller every time you enter back again.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you were looking for:

Ionic caches your views and thus your controllers by default (max of 10)
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

There are events you can hook onto to let your controller do certain things based on those ionic events. see here for an example:
http://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-changes/

Comment: Can be improved by showing example code instead of simply sharing a link

Comment: Is there anything like this on Angular Js as well?

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin by default, any code, IIFE or function that you declare and run inside your main controller function will be executed each time the view (and thus controller) is loaded. If you need events like execute a function once in the lifetime of your application, check out angular-ui-router sticky states and ```ViewContentLoading``` and ```ViewContentLoaded``` events :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with ionic where I was trying to load the native camera as soon as I select the camera tab. I resolved the issue by setting the controller to the ion-view component for the camera tab (in tabs.html) and then calling the $scope method that loads my camera (addImage).

In www/templates/tabs.html

```
  <ion-tab title="Camera" icon-off="ion-camera" icon-on="ion-camera" href="#/tab/chats" ng-controller="AddMediaCtrl" ng-click="addImage()">
    <ion-nav-view  name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
```

The addImage method, defined in AddMediaCtrl loads the native camera every time the user clicks the "Camera" tab. I did **not** have to change anything in the angular cache for this to work.  I hope this helps.