# How to force refresh the cached source files upon Ionic build/run?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have this random issue with `ionic build` or `ionic run`.

I've noticed that during compilation it uses the cache of my source code, therefore when making new changes it doesn't reflect upon re-compiling the app.

So my question is, how can you clear the cache for the build files? I've tried doing `ionic state reset` but still it doesn't work nor doing uninstall then re-install the app from my Android.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to clear the view cache in Ionic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676631/is-it-possible-to-clear-the-view-cache-in-ionic)

Comment: @SwapnilShende I think this isn't a duplicate question, because my issue is with the Ionic build not with views.

Comment: Does this really happen? I am not sure on this. If you can reproduce it, then open an issue on github

Comment: @InfinitePrime yes, I'm stuck with the build for an hour already, I've doubled check everything but it seems it's using a cached source files upon building. I'll try to investigate on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @InfinitePrime Yes it really happens. All of a sudden it started happening in my ionic. And no matter what I do, clear browser history, restart IIS and all crazy stuff, my ionic is stuck with 2 days old changes.

Comment: 2 years and this still seems like an issue because it is happening to me. What's the point of live reload if it doesn't reload? To have to reinit the platform each time is ludicrous.

Comment: in which platform are you facing this problem. I think you are facing problem in ios.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What I did to solve my problem was to do re-initialize the Android platform.

`ionic cordova platform remove android` then `ionic cordova platform add android`

goto task manager and kill java se process

Comment: in ionic 2 use `ionic cordova platform update android`

Comment: For ionic 3 i used :

`ionic cordova platform remove android`

`ionic cordova platform add android<br>`

Comment: I've solved a similiar problem in Ionic V3 with: `cordova clean`

Answer (score 13):

You need to increment your app version on your config.xml (at the top of your project folder) to reflect your changes before running:

```
<widget id="com.yourapp.id" version="0.0.8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
```

On this example, increment the attribute version to 0.0.9: `version="0.0.9"`.

Then `run android` or `run ios`.

Comment: the fast way, if you are changing something on the config.xml.

Comment: I've run remove and add platform won't work, and this is the only solution work if remove and add platform wont change anything

Answer (score 8):

Remove platform :

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

Re add platform :

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Step 1) copy www folder specific platform

```
ionic cordova prepare android
```

Step 2) build apk

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Step 3) deploy latest apk in device

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use cordova build, `sudo cordova build <platform>`

```
sudo cordova prepare
```

at your cordova project root folder.

this command reflects your changes to builds(all platforms).

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bug with Ionic, but to fix it usually I just ctrl+c then gulp and then re-run ionic serve.

Answer (score 4):

I have deleted `android-debug.apk` from `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk` and then `ionic cordova run android`. It worked with no cache.

Answer (score 2):

Would like to answer this question as it wasted some real valuable time for me.

I emptied the `platforms` folder and build the solution again. BTW, I am using Visual Studio for development. And I should solve the problem.

Also it is quite obvious but still wanted to reiterate that platforms should not be part of source control.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ionic repair
```

This is a full clean build of all yur packages
Official Documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/repair

Comment: This also works for `pwa` build problems, not just Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem where the app would load most recent changes locally using `npm run dev` but when I tried to run on my device with `cordova run android` it would load an old version. I tried all of the suggestions above and nothing worked. I finally figured out that if I did an `npm run build` before I did the build with cordova to my device, it would load the new version. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

No need to remove and add platform instead clear project file

For android users

```
cd android 

.gradlew clean
```

For ios users

```
cd ios
xcodebuild clean
```

final step

```
npx jetify

npx cap sync
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement the solution by @Renesaensz, in ionic 4.5.0 (or greater version) add **cordova** to the commands:

- ionic **cordova** platform remove android

then ionic

- ionic **cordova** platform add android

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the plugin files present in `node_modules`, I also had to remove `plugins` and `www` folders, prior to regenerating the platform.

Answer (score 0):

cordova clean and closed all open files worked for me.