# Call init on cached view in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple angular js ionic application. When I route for the first time to a view then the init function gets called. However any subsequent visits to the same view do not call the init function. I know this is probably called because cache is set to true by default on the app:

```
.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    templateUrl: "templates/mainpage.html",
    controller : "appController"
  })
```

A simple controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', []).controller('appController', function($scope) {
    var init = function() { alert("test"); }
});
```

My index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter" class="ng-cloak">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

How can I make sure that init gets called each time the view is loaded?

Comment: Try adding something to call `init` explicitly on load of the controller.. try adding `init();` after your function declaration.

Comment: Already tried that to add init at the end of the controller. It doesn't get called.

Comment: controller names don't match in code shown and `init()` is never called. Hard to troubleshoot pseudo code that isn't valid. Create a demo that replicates your problem

Comment: Sure. I will try to create one asap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function everytime a view loads, take a look at ng-init.

Here's an example from [Run a controller function whenever a view is opened/shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058276/run-a-controller-function-whenever-a-view-is-opened-shown):

HTML:

```
<ion-nav-view ng-controller="indexController" name="other" ng-init="doSomething()"></ion-nav-view>
```