# $scope value in ionic angularjs is not updates the side-menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am stuck with an issue in my **ionic app** that has a side menu with `name` and `picture` and it's parent and `abstract:true`. In that same controller, there is an update function where it updates `scope.picture`, but the side menu picture is not updated.

```
controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$window,$rootScope,$location,$http,$state,$cordovaCamera,$ionicLoading,$q,login_Service) 
{               
    $scope.user_Name=$rootScope.u_name;            
    $scope.uid=$rootScope.user_id;
    $scope.pass=$rootScope.password;
    $scope.user_Picture=$rootScope.pic;
    $scope.whats=$rootScope.wh; 

    $scope.update_u=function(topic){      
        $scope.user_Picture=topic['picture']; 
        $scope.whats=topic['e_whats'];
    }                  
});

this is side-menu template 

<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-light nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">

    <!-- Sidebar Content -->
    <ion-content class="gem-sidebar dark">
      <!-- Profile Box - Extends ionic's .row -->
      <div class="row gem-sidebar-profile-box">
        <!-- Profile Thumb -->
        <div class="col col-25">
          <img src="img/gemionic/no-photo.jpg" ng-if="!user_Picture" class="gem-profile-image" alt="">
           <img src="http://www.cssolutionshub.com/php/images/user_img/{{user_Picture}}" ng-if="user_Picture" class="gem-profile-image">
        </div> 
        <!-- End Profile Thumb -->

        <!-- Profile Name -->
        <div class="col col-50">



          <h6> <a menu-close href="#" ng-click="edit_prof()">Edit Profile</a></h6>
          <h5 ng-if="user_Name !== undefined">{{user_Name}}</h5>
          <h4>{{whats}}</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- End Profile Name <a -->

        <!-- Account Settings Icon -->
        <div class="col col-25 gem-text-center">
          <i class="gem-profile-settings-icon ion-volume-high"></i>
        </div>
        <!-- End Account Settings Icon -->

      </div>
      <!-- End Profile Box -->
      <!--<ion-list>        
        <ion-item class="item-ng-click" nav-clear menu-close ng-click="login()">Login</ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/feed">Feed</ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/start">Starter View</ion-item>


      </ion-list> -->
    </ion-content>
    <!-- End sidemenu content -->
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

and this is my edit template where update function is clicked

```
<!-- Title for header bar (refer to www/index.html) -->
<ion-view title="Edit Profile">
  <!-- ======================
  LEFT SIDE BUTTON
  ====================== -->
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <!-- ======================
  RIGHT SIDE BUTTON
  ====================== -->
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-checkmark-circled"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>


  <!-- ======================
  MAIN CONTENT SECTION
  ====================== -->
  <ion-content class="has-header gem-ion-content profile-edit">
    <!-- ======================
    GEMIONIC PROFILE ADD PICTURE BANNER
    ====================== -->
    <!-- <div class="gem-profile-media">
      <div class="gem-profile-details profile2">
        <div class="text-center">
          <i class="icon ion-plus-circled add-user-pic-icon"></i>
          <p class="uppercase">Add user pic</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> -->
     <img ng-if="topic.picture !== undefined && img===undefined " ng-src="http://www.cssolutionshub.com/php/images/user_img/{{topic.picture}}" alt="" width="100%" height="20%" ng-click="addMedia()"> 

             <img ng-if="topic.picture === undefined && img===undefined" ng-src="img/gemionic/no-photo.jpg" width="100%" height="20%" ng-click="addMedia()"> 
              <img src="{{img}}" ng-if="img!==undefined" width="100%" height="20%" ng-click="addMedia()">
    <!-- ======================
    END GEMIONIC PROFILE ADD PICTURE BANNER
    ====================== -->

    <!-- Standard Ionic List -->
    <div class="list">

      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">What Now</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="topic.whats">
      </label>    

      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="password" ng-model="topic.password">
      </label>
    <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click='update_u(topic)'>
      Update
  </button>
  <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click='go_feed()'>
      Cancel
  </button>
</div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: what bit of code is calling `$scope.update_u()`??

Comment: for updating user picture inside same controller

Comment: I see what it is supposed to do. You have made it into a function / method for that `$scope` so where is your code that calls it / what triggers it to execute? This will help people identify the problem

Comment: try with $rootScope.user_Picture..!

Comment: thanks for comment but $rootScope value will not update

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$scope.update_u=function(topic){
  $scope.whats = topic.whats;   
  $scope.user_Picture=topic['picture'];
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick comment ,i used apply it did'nt work then how to make side menu picture should be updated plz help

Comment: Can you share your html or the part of the controller where you call this updater function?

Comment: Are you stuck on "no-photo.jpg" or are you seeing a different picture?

Comment: exactly my problem is to upadate status that is $scope.whats =topic['e_whats'] ; but side menu is not taking updating value

Comment: plz Javier Conde help me

Comment: Where is that `topic` coming from? I see you using it but it's not defined anywhere. Can you check via `console.log` you are receiving an object at `update_u`?

Comment: topic is parameter ,after update function triggers new updated value is shown in console.log but that is not updated in side-menu

Comment: topic  displays      Object {password: "l", picture: "", whats: "i m gttrhtkjh,hkj"}

Comment: Can you double check that the side-menu is inside `ng-app` (under the influence of the controller)?

Comment: Your update function is only updating the picture, you should add `$scope.whats = topic.whats;` to it. Picture is not getting updated because it's empty. I've edited my answer to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (inside the AppCtrl). The code inside $ionicView.beforeEnter function will be executed everytime the view is called:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
      // Code you want executed every time view is opened
      $scope.update_u=function(topic){      
          $scope.user_Picture=topic['picture']; 
          $scope.whats=topic['e_whats'];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also may be due to caching of your controller. You can stop it at the route.js by using `cache: false,` line.  [See this for a similar solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058276/run-a-controller-function-whenever-a-view-is-opened-shown)