# Angular controller not working on ion-nav-view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm just starting to learn Angular + Ionic, so pardon any potential ignorance :)

After, following the sample from [Ionic's website](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) I'm trying to expand upon it by assigning an ng-controller to my ion-nav-view.  I'd like to use that so I can then listen for the `$ionicView.enter` on all the child views at one time, instead of having to do that separately inside of each child controller.

I add my controller like so:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view ng-controller="NavViewController"></ion-nav-view>
```

But it never actually executes the controller's constructor.  If I move the assignment of the ng-controller up a level (e.g. the body element), it works fine.  Is there any reason as to why that wouldn't work when assigned onto the ion-nav-view directly?

*EDIT*

Here's a codepen (trying to figure out why NavViewController isn't getting called):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxYYkN

Comment: where are you setting ng-app?

Comment: please share some more code

Comment: From the tutorial, ng-app is set on the <html> tag.  I added a codepen link to the desc.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060951/5409081)
Sorry that I didn't researched enough and misunderstood the article I read.

Comment: Where does it say in the documentation that it's not built for having a ng-controller?

Comment: My bad it's possible. Here it is read the answer. I will update my later. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27060951/5409081

Comment: sorry i forgot it. please give me sometime to figure it out.